# OpenCV modification and re-compiling

Tags: ros, opencv, compile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I need to modify an OpenCV module (ML) and I would like to know how I can do it for the version of OpenCV included in ROS.

Thank you
Walter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10208/opencv-modification-and-re-compiling/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2011-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Walter, it is not recommended to recompile the source if you installed via debs. In fact, for OpenCV, the source won't even be there as it is cleaned out after compilation and before the deb is built.

What you should do is to checkout a source version of the [stack containing OpenCV](http://www.ros.org/wiki/vision_opencv), into your own directory and make changes there.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0